# NHibernate exception collection [..User.Groups] was not processed by flush()

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception

All of my NH entities derive from a type called BusinessEntity, it
has the most basic values ID, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy.

CreatedBy / UpdatedBy takes a User

I have a IPreUpdateEventListener and IPreInsertEventListener that fire
to get the current DateTime for the audit values. Also in here I have
my logic to get the current user running which I grab by running a
criteria query against the windows user principle. From what I
understood from all of post on the NH user group on this subject my User class needs
to be eagerly loaded for this to work correctly in my EventListeners
this is how I load the user

```
public User GetByDomainPrinciple(string domainPrinciple)
{
    var domainPrincipleCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<User>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("DomainPrinciple", domainPrinciple))
        .SetFetchMode("Roles", FetchMode.Eager)
        .SetFetchMode("Groups", FetchMode.Eager)
        .SetFetchMode("Groups.Roles", FetchMode.Eager)
        .SetCacheable(true);

    return Repository.QuerySingle(domainPrincipleCriteria);
}
```

`Repository.QuerySingle(domainPrincipleCriteria);` is just

```
return detachedCriteria
.GetExecutableCriteria(_conversation.Session).UniqueResult<T>();
```

Am I missing something or is my criteria query wrong? I guess absolute
worst case scenario I could change CreatedBy to be a Guid instead of a
User and just manually assign the FK like that, but that seems very
dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you. The error stems from the PreUpdateEventListener. I had the same issue while back.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx

Comment: Unless I'm missing something useful in the comments this isn't helpful this is where I got the code for my event listener except I call NH from the event listener to get the user instead of just using the windows principle like his example.

Comment: I think if you are loading anything in there it will give you this error. I tried to get an answer to this question in NH user groups also, as well as couple other folks, with no answer. http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/1db7fd843b0b4b56/cdaa52f93e94e167?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=epitka#cdaa52f93e94e167. I am sorry I was not of more help.

Comment: This wasn't very helpful, so I'm surprised it's marked as a solution.

Comment: @asbjornu this was marked as the solution because it just wasn't possible, can't load data from NH in that context at all.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in NHibernate that could be fixed with custom DefaultFlushEventListener. See answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11575172/1389546