# An NHibernate audit trail that doesn't cause "collection was not processed by flush" errors

Tags: nhibernate

Ayende has an article about how to implement a simple audit trail for NHibernate ([here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/30/avoid-soft-deletes.aspx)) using event handlers.

Unfortunately, as can be seen in the comments, his implementation causes the following exception to be thrown: *collection xxx was not processed by flush()*

The problem appears to be the implicit call to *ToString* on the dirty properties, which can cause trouble if the dirty property is also a mapped entity.

I have tried my hardest to build a working implementation but with no luck.

Does anyone know of a working solution?

Comment: Just to clarify, I want a solution that doesn't involve sacrificing lazy-loading or other important functionality. I also want a solution that is developer-safe - the exception can be thrown very intermittently for highly obscure reason, and is often almost impossible to replicate or debug.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve the same problem using following workaround: set the processed flag to true on all collections in the current persistence context within the listener

```
public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent postEvent)
{
    if (IsAuditable(postEvent.Entity))
    {
       //skip application specific code

        foreach (var collection in postEvent.Session.PersistenceContext.CollectionEntries.Values)
        {
            var collectionEntry = collection as CollectionEntry;
            collectionEntry.IsProcessed = true;
        }

        //var session = postEvent.Session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);
        //session.Save(auditTrailEntry);
        //session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any idea what (potentially unwanted) side-effects setting `IsProcessed` to `true` might have?

Answer (score 8):

The fix should be the following. Create a new event listener class and derive it from NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener:

```
[Serializable] 
public class FixedDefaultFlushEventListener: DefaultFlushEventListener 
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    protected override void PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
    {
        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            log.Debug("executing flush");
        }
        try
        {
            session.ConnectionManager.FlushBeginning();
            session.PersistenceContext.Flushing = true;
            session.ActionQueue.PrepareActions();
            session.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions();
        }
        catch (HibernateException exception)
        {
            if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                log.Error("Could not synchronize database state with session", exception);
            }
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.PersistenceContext.Flushing = false;
            session.ConnectionManager.FlushEnding();
        }

    }
}
```

Register it during NHibernate configuraiton:

```
cfg.EventListeners.FlushEventListeners = new IFlushEventListener[] { new FixedDefaultFlushEventListener() };
```

You can read more about this bug in Hibernate JIRA:
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2763

The next release of NHibernate should include that fix either.

Comment: Just to add context to the comment: "Next release should include that fix". As of 3.3.3GA it doesn't appear to be merged, so still useful to have this.

Comment: Is this fix also valid for DefaultAutoFlushEventListener? It appears both Listeners support from the problem, I wasn't sure the same code should be used by both.

Comment: Exactly. It should be integrated into DefaultAutoFlushEventListener, no luck to see it in NHibernate release yet. See: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/143

Answer (score 4):

This is not easy at all. I wrote something like this, but it is very specific to our needs and not trivial.

Some additional hints:

You can test if references are loaded using

```
NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(entity)
```

or

```
NHibernateUtil.IsPropertyInitialized(entity, propertyName)
```

You can cast collections to the `IPersistentCollection`. I implemented an `IInterceptor` where I get the NHibernate Type of each property, I don't know where you can get this when using events:

```
if (nhtype.IsCollectionType)
{
    var collection = previousValue as NHibernate.Collection.IPersistentCollection;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        // just skip uninitialized collections
        if (!collection.WasInitialized)
        {
            // skip
        }
        else
        {
            // read collections previous values
            previousValue = collection.StoredSnapshot;
        }
    }
}
```

When you get the update event from NHibernate, the instance is initialized. You can safely access properties of primitive types. When you want to use `ToString`, make sure that your `ToString` implementation doesn't access any referenced entities nor any collections.

You may use NHibernate meta-data to find out if a type is mapped as an entity or not. This could be useful to navigate in your object model. When you reference another entity, you will get additional update events on this when it changed.

Comment: You can get the type out of the event persister using `@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[propertyIndex].IsCollectionType` and `@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[propertyIndex].IsAssociationType`. Even with access to these, I still haven't figured out how to audit associated entity types.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that this error is thrown when application code loads a Lazy Propery where the Entity has a collection.

My first attempt involed watching for new `CollectionEntries` (which I've never want to process as there shouldn't actually be any changes). Then mark them as `IsProcessed = true` so they wouldn't cause problems.

```
var collections = args.Session.PersistenceContext.CollectionEntries;
var collectionKeys = args.Session.PersistenceContext.CollectionEntries.Keys;
var roundCollectionKeys = collectionKeys.Cast<object>().ToList();
var collectionValuesClount = collectionKeys.Count;

// Application code that that loads a Lazy propery where the Entity has a collection

var postCollectionKeys = collectionKeys.Cast<object>().ToList();
var newLength = postCollectionKeys.Count;

if (newLength != collectionValuesClount) {

    foreach (var newKey in postCollectionKeys.Except(roundCollectionKeys)) {
        var collectionEntry = (CollectionEntry)collections[newKey];
        collectionEntry.IsProcessed = true;
    }
}
```

However this didn't entirly solve the issue. In some cases I'd still get the exception.

When `OnPostUpdate` is called the values in the `CollectionEntries` dictionary should all already be set to `IsProcessed = true`. So I decided to do an extra check to see if the collections not processed matched what I expected.

```
var valuesNotProcessed = collections.Values.Cast<CollectionEntry>().Where(x => !x.IsProcessed).ToList();

if (valuesNotProcessed.Any()) {
    // Assert: valuesNotProcessed.Count() == (newLength - collectionValuesClount)
}
```

In the cases that my first attempt fixed these numbers would match exactly. However in the cases where it didn't work there were extra items alreay in the dictionary. In my I could be sure these extra items also wouldn't result in updates so I could just set `IsProcessed = true` for all the `valuesNotProcessed`.