# NHibernate Event Listender Deep Clone Object

Tags: c#, events, nhibernate, reflection

I'm trying to get the old state of an updated entity in the OnPostUpdate event. The OldState property of the @event argument returns the object as an array and I need it as an object. I tried the following:

```
public class EventListener : IPostUpdateEventListener {
    public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent @event) {
        // Get the property names to align with the indexes of the old state
        var propertyNames = @event.Persister.PropertyNames;

        // Get the original entity values
        var type = @event.Entity.GetType();
        var original = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // Set the values
    for (var i = 0; i < @event.OldState.Length; i++) {
        // Get the property and value
        var property = type.GetProperty(@event.Persister.PropertyNames[i]);
        var value = @event.OldState[i];

        if (property.CanWrite && !(@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is CollectionType)) {
            if (value != null && (@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is ComponentType || @event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is EntityType))
                property.SetValue(original, CloneObject(value));
            else
                property.SetValue(original, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the CloneObject method:

```
private object CloneObject(object source) {
    var sourceType = source.GetType();
    var target = Activator.CreateInstance(sourceType, true);

    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties()) {
        var value = property.GetValue(source, null);

        if (property.CanWrite && (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)) && !property.PropertyType.IsInterface) {
            if (value != null && typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                property.SetValue(target, CloneObject(value));
            else
                property.SetValue(target, value);
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```

The first thing I do is loop over the properties in the original object and then I try to handle components and reference types (ignoring lists). This copies the object correctly. However it then throws the error:

> collection [Models.ContentType.Tags] was not processed by flush()

**Edit:** The ContentType class is the type for one of the properties I am updating. Here is it's implementation incase it helps:

```
public class ContentType : Entity<int> {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ContentTag> Tags { get; set; }

    public ContentType() {
        Tags = new List<ContentTag>();
    }
}
```

I'm also getting similar errors when I try to get the old state for other entities. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me the correct way to do this. Thanks

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Whenever it updates an entity I get the error "collection [Models.User.Addresses] was not processed by flush()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit

Although you do not seem to be touching any collection, regarding this issue  :

[Collection was not processed by flush when iterate through collection in PostUpdateEvent](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1882)

you may give a try to this answer, to ensure it is not the cause of your problem :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11575172/1236044

---

Knowing the line which triggers the error would really help.

Also what is `CloneObject` in `property.SetValue(target, CloneObject(value));` ?

Have you tried moving the two lines `var value = ...` inside the corresponding `if` statements ? This way you would process the value only when really needed.

```
    var value = @event.OldState[i];

    if (property.CanWrite && !(@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is CollectionType)) {
        if (value != null && (@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is ComponentType || @event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is EntityType))
```

becoming

```
    if (property.CanWrite && !(@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is CollectionType)) {
        var value = @event.OldState[i];
        if (value != null && (@event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is ComponentType || @event.Persister.PropertyTypes[i] is EntityType))
```

and

```
    var value = property.GetValue(source, null);

    if (property.CanWrite && (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)) && !property.PropertyType.IsInterface) {
        if (value != null && typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
```

becoming

```
    if (property.CanWrite && (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)) && !property.PropertyType.IsInterface) {
        var value = property.GetValue(source, null);
        if (value != null && typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
```

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question. CloneObject is the correct name of the private method. I was merging my new solution from an earlier version and must have missed renaming one of the occurrences. However I have done as you have said but the problem remains. I have edited my question with the ContentType class which is a property of the entity I am updating.

Comment: Thanks I applied the patch to the IFlushEventListener and that cleared up this error. However I get another problem later down the line. Since it was not part of the original question I will mark this as the answer. Thanks